# How to change image based on who logged in

Tags: php, image, authentication

I need help on how to make image change after a user logged in. 'coz i'm creating a online radio station and i want my listeners to see who's DJ is currently on-air based on that image. that image is stored in a php page(djonair.php), the image inside that page(djonair.php) will change after the user logged in. then that page is called in the main page(index.html) using iframe. I'm using iframe to call that page because my main page is a HTML page(index.html).

here's my login.php code:

```
    <?
    session_start();
    if(session_is_registered(myusername)){
    header("location:djmain.php");
    }
    ?>

    <font face="calibri" color="white" size="6">: DJ Log In :</font><br>
    <table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <tr>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
    <td>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#005180">
    <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><strong>Member Login </strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="78">Username</td>
    <td width="6">:</td>
    <td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input name="mypassword" type="password" id="mypassword"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </form>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

here's the code for my checklogin.php:

```
    <?php
    $host="sqlhostname"; // Host name
    $username="sqlusername"; // Mysql username
    $password="sqkpassword"; // Mysql password
    $db_name="dbname"; // Database name
    $tbl_name="tablename"; // Table name

    // Connect to server and select databse.
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

    // username and password sent from form
    $myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
    $mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

    // To protect MySQL injection
    $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
    $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
    $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
    $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

    $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
    // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

    if($count==1){
    // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
    session_register("myusername");
    session_register("mypassword");
    header("location:djmain.php");
    }
    else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    echo '<br>Go back to <a href="login.php">log-in</a> page.';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Have you even attempted to do it?

Answer (score 0):

change some record in database where you store djs with image url and then select it everytime user access page so he/she can she who's in air. For example

```
$q = "UPDATE statistics SET on_Air_image_url = '".mysql_real_Escape_string($_SESSION['djname']).".png'";
```

Comment: where should i put that? sorry for a dumb question. 'coz i'm a beginner on PHP/MySQL coding. Thanks! :)

Comment: can you teach me how to do that? 'coz i really don't know how. :(

Comment: @sedrik: you've got DJ's login. put this query AFTER that login query

Comment: @sedrik: after `if($count == 1)` add   `$sql="UPDATE statistics SET on_Air_image_url = '".mysql_real_Escape_string($myusername).".png';mysql_query($sql);`

Comment: under if($count == 1)?? and what fieldname should i name in my database? and in that field should i put the image-url?

Comment: how can i select another data from the row. for example i logged in. i want all the datas on my row will store on session. i have 5 rows: id, username, password, djname, and dj_img_url. thanks! :)

Comment: @sedrik: try to look on some tutorials how-to php & mysql first ;)

Comment: i googled it. but no luck. i can't find any tutorial on how to do this. :(

Comment: i'm already done on retrieving the image url from database. i used cookies instead of session. the image is changing but i'm the only one who can see the image. but my listeners can't see the image. what should i do? :(